# AWS User is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, postman, aws-api-gateway, auth0

I'm new to AWS API Gateway and Lambda and I am wondering if anyone could help?

[image]

- I generate an access token using Auth0 and it works on postman returning all of the correct JSON data for the first lambda function call
- When I call the second lambda function on postman it says that the user is not Authorised for this  resource:

"Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource"

and

```
403 Forbidden
```

This only lasts for exactly 5 mins and then I can call the second function on Postman but cannot call the first anymore with the same error.

Any ideas as to how I can solve this

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing the `x-api-key` header?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I dont think thats the issue as it works for the first request but will not work for 5 mins on the second call

Answer (score 11, accepted):

was also running into this issue. Turns out my authorizer had caching enabled which meant it would reuse the same policy previously generated. The TTL of the cache defaults to 5 minutes.

On the dashboard, you can access the authorizers and disable the caching to stop this from happening or change the policy being generated to allow for all resources.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your answer! I solved this in two ways. 1. the way that you did it and 2. I added `Cache-Control : no-cache` to the header

Comment: You need to also re-deploy the API after disabling caching.

Comment: the exact issue we had even though there was never a valid case for it to issue a deny policy! very weird, but glad I found your answer

Comment: As mentioned by @jrc, Redeploying is required otherwise these changes won't be affected. Make sure you redeploy. But, sometimes deployment skips if there are no changes, in that case, you can add one extra space/line in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably caching related on a lambda authorizer. The default TTL on a lambda authorizer is 300 secs (5 mins), the max is 1 hour. So if you hold 5 mins the issue may clear. To flush the cache you can set ReauthorizeEvery to 0 (secs) and redeploy, so you always see the actual response (not cached) until you have resolved the underlying issue, then reset the TTL to 300 secs.

AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-lambdarequestauthorizationidentity.html

AWS SAM/ Cloudformation template.yaml:

```
  myAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Description: Some API description
      Name: someAPIName
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Type: REGIONAL
      StageName: !Ref EnvType # dev or prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
        Authorizers:
          AuthFunction:
            FunctionPayloadType: REQUEST
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthFunction.Arn # your auth lambda
            Identity:
              Headers: # amend as you require
                - username
                - password
              ReauthorizeEvery: 0
```